# Hide the navigation bar in a Storyboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I'm using a story board for the first time to create a ios app.  The app usses a navinagtion controller, and the storyboard puts a navigation bar on the top of each view.  Is there a way to remove the navigation bar? I tried clicking on it and pressing the del key did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first visible view controller run this line of code.

> self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

or uncheck `Bar Visibility` in the inspector:

[image: image from the inspector]

In situations where you have more than one view controller: You only have to do this in the first view controller, which appears.  It will then stay hidden throughout the app.  (You may prefer to set it on every view controller, simply because you may change the flow of the app.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of achieving the same thing:

In your storyboard, click on your first navigation controller, and then un-check **Shows Navigation Bar**:

[image]

Alternatively you can do the same in code. Add:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

in your first viewController's `viewWillAppear:` method.

To make the navBar visible, you can add

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

in a subsequent view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do Anything

in the Main.Storyboard go to ViewController and in the Attribute Inspector. "Top Bar = None"

---

Open Image For Better Understanding

step 1 -> [Open Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyi0t.png)
step 2 -> [Open Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhCdE.png)

Comment: Please upload images and not just provide links to them.